# angularjs assigning array with $scope

Tags: arrays, angularjs, scope

Here's my problem. I try to assign a data array like this from a function,

```
function func1(){
  // some code //       
  $scope.data = arr;           
}
```

but when i try to take values from another function

```
function func2() { 
   var value = $scope.data[1];
}
```

it gives a error. But it works perfectly inside the first function

Comment: can you check if `func2` is getting called before `func1` or `$scope.data` contains undefined value? debug your code using `f12` key in chrome

Comment: That probably means that func2() is executed *before* the array is assigned to the scope. That's all we can say based on the tiny information you provided.

Comment: No it doesnt. if i assign like $scope.data= arr[1]; it perfectly works

Comment: see - https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging

Comment: Declare $scope.data=[]  above both function.

Comment: are these functions are inside the same controller? are we supposed to guess what the rest of your code looks like?